# Erro no Login Azure pelo PowerShell do windows

Tags: microsoft-azure, powershell

Dados: sdk do azure baixados

Windows: 10

Erro ao fazer login no azure pelo powershell:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como corrigir este erro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou instalar o módulo Azure no seu PowerShell - execute com privilégios de Administrador.

```
PS> Get-Module PowerShellGet -list | Select-Object Name,Version,Path
PS> Install-Module Azure
```

Veja a documentação completa aqui: [Instalação do módulo Azure PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/azure/servicemanagement/install-azure-ps?view=azuresmps-4.0.0)